# C# RPG - Ability Cooldown Issues

Tags: c#

I am working on an RPG and started working on ability cooldowns. I have a player that is controlled by the user (player1), and a player controlled by the computer (player2) for testing purposes. The cooldown for abilities work perfectly for the user controlled player, but when it comes to the AI, the computer will not execute the ability unless the computer goes first (when the ability is off cooldown by default). Below is the code I think is relevant to the question, but if more information is needed I will update the post.

The ability class:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class attackList : MonoBehaviour{

public int dmg;
public float coolDown;
public float _attackTimer;

public void Attack1(basePlayer user, basePlayer target, int D)
{
   coolDown = 2.5f;

    if (user._attackTimer == 0)
    {
        dmg = D;
        user._attackTimer = coolDown;
        target.curHealth -= dmg;
    }
}

public void cooldown(basePlayer user)
{
    if (user._attackTimer > 0) {
        user._attackTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (user._attackTimer < 0) {
           user._attackTimer = 0;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The attack logic class:

```
 public class attackLogic : MonoBehaviour {

private attackList _attackList = new attackList();
private playerList _playerList = new playerList();

public bool player1_turn = false;  //player1 is not allowed to go first by default
public bool player2_turn = false;  //player2 is not allowed to go first by default

void Start()
{
    int rnd = Random.Range (1,3); // random value between 1 and 2 generated, which will determine what player goes first

    if (rnd == 1)
    {
        player1_turn = true;
    }
    if (rnd == 2)
    {
        player2_turn = true;
    }

    //current health set to the maximum health at the beginning of each fight
    _playerList.player1.curHealth = _playerList.player1.maxHealth;
    _playerList.player2.curHealth = _playerList.player2.maxHealth;
}

void Update()
{
    Logic(); //run through the logic of the battle

}

public void Logic()
{
    if (player1_turn == true)
    {
        _attackList.cooldown(_playerList.player1);
        if (Input.GetKeyUp("1"))
        {
           _attackList.Attack1(_playerList.player1, _playerList.player2, 5);
            player1_turn = false;
            player2_turn = true;
        }
    }


    if (player2_turn == true)
    {
        _attackList.cooldown(_playerList.player2);
        _attackList.Attack1(_playerList.player2, _playerList.player1, 5);    
            player1_turn = true;
            player2_turn = false;
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: I wonder if the issue might be related to the way you have your `if` blocks set up. Namely, in the first block, you set `player2_turn = true`, and then in the second block, you immediately check if `player2_turn == true`, so you end up assessing two players' turns on the same update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  I have a nasty suspicion that the actual problem is in Time.deltaTime, but you didn't show the code so I can't confirm this.

2)  Since you have time-based code here you can't expect it to behave the same when you step through the code.  Thus it often helps to dust off some of the old techniques--namely, print statements.  Of course things have changed enough over the years that it's become write but the ideas still work.  Take a part of the screen that isn't important to what you're testing and write the variables out that are involved in what you are doing.  I think you'll find player 2 is cooling down extremely slowly.

3)  I think you need a better understanding of objects.  You appear to be simply using them as containers.  I also dislike player1 and player2--you should simply have a list of players.  Remember how the WOPR was defeated in *War Games*?--that can be very useful at times in balancing things.

Comment: In case anyone doesn't know, the WOPR was defeated by having the it play itself

Comment: Thank you Loren for your reply. Unfortunately I cannot provide the time.deltatime script because it is a Monobehaviour which is provided by Unity, however here is the link to the documentation for function https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out my misuse of objects, I will be sure to do further research. I will create a list of players as per your recommendation.

Comment: @TimothyWhite That shoots down my idea.  I think you'll have to debug this the way I'm talking about.

Comment: Between the suggestions of LorenPechtel and Abion47 I have noticed a few things, namely that: 1) player1 works fine and the cooldown values update without any problem. 2) player2 will only update the cooldown values if I manually press 1 (which is the key bound to attack1) repeatedly until the cooldown of player2 reaches 0, then it will remove health from player1. I'll tinker with the code a bit then post back if I fix it. Hopefully this info should help in solving the issue.

Comment: @TimothyWhite Oh, now I see it!  If you don't press 1 then player 2 never gets a turn.  Revamping the logic like I suggested would eliminate this problem.